# What stat test to use, ANOVA, correlation? Comparing control with experimental group

Tags: correlation, anova, spss

I am really hoping someone can help me. I have my data all collected however I am really struggling how to analyse it. My supervisor is away and so I am kind of left here panicking over how to properly analyse my results.

I am trying to see whether people who are faster at categorising faces by emotion are also better at the emotional flanker task and subsequently better on the incongruent trials (conflict). In all, I want to see if there is a correlation between performance on a facial categorisation task and their performance on the flanker test. I think I am correct in saying a pearsons correlation is ok here. This was a repeated measures design by the way.

But I have also incorporated a normal flanker task as the control group, to remove confounding effects i.e. are people just fast at the flanker task in general. I want to disentangle their performance on the emotional flanker from the neutral flanker, but I do not know how to do this. I was guessing to do a two by two ANOVA (emotional flanker: congruent and incongruent) versus the neutral flanker (congruent and incongruent) and then interpreting the interaction effect but something tells me this is incorrect? My results show a correlation between performance on the emotional flanker and the neutral flanker so how do I disentangle their performance to see if it was truly to the IV or something else?

Comment: Please tell us what your observed variables are. On each trial in face categorization task, are you measuring response time and whether a face is categorized correctly? How is the performance measured in the emotional flanker task? Is it response time as well? EDIT: I'm a psychologist and I have no clue what emotional flanker task is, so perhaps you could describe the task in detail.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. Sorry for my ambiguity. I am measuring reaction time in the face categorisation task, reaction time in the neutral flanker and reaction time in the emotional flanker. the emotional flanker is a modificiation of the Eriksen flanker task but using faces as the stimuli opposed to letters or arrows. So the DV throughout is reaction time. There will be a target face in the middle, and the two faces beside it will either be congruent or incongruent to that face. participants simply have to state what emotion the middle face is showing by pressing the correct keys

Comment: continued.. whilst ignoring the distracting stimuli around it. so I want to know whether people who are faster at classifying faces would also be faster at the emotional flanker and they are then better at the incongruent version (the conflict version which requires inhibition)

Comment: Thanks for details. What happens if the observer presses the incorrect key in the flanker task? Ditto, what happens if the face is not categorized correctly in the face categorization task? (how many categories are there?) Do You exclude the response times for the incorrect responses from your sample?

Comment: In the flanker, if they press the incorrect key, then this will be marked as an incorrect response - this also goes for the facial categorization task (there are 40 faces to categorise). I do have data for accuracy however I wasn't sure whether to include them in the analysis. The experiment was done on E-Prime and the RT's and accuracy for all three tasks were converted into SPSS so I actually am unsure what happened to the incorrect responses for the RT and whether EPrime does something to this. Had 21 participants, by the way.

Comment: Have you looked at the proportion of incorrect responses? If it's large You probably don't want to exclude them...

Comment: Will probably keep incorrect responses in analysis and then was thinking of excluding the RT's which were considered outliers?

Comment: Ok, back to face categorization: what I meant was the number face categories - e.g. happy, sad, angry ... How many of these are there?

Comment: There are just happy and sad (different variations. some are very obviously happy whereas others not so obvious) to keep brief. Same with the emotional flanker task.

Answer (score 0):

The main difficulty is that Your measures provide You with response time and accuracy while You are interested in the performance of a participant irrespective of their speed-accuracy trade-off. [This question](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/660/how-to-analyze-reaction-times-and-accuracy-together?noredirect=1&lq=1) discusses the analysis of response times and accuracy. It points out that the linear methods are not recommended and suggests a model-based approach.

In your case, you may wish to fit a times/accuracy model for each participant and for each of the three tasks (face categorization, emotional flanker, neutral flanker task). This will provide you with a single-valued mean estimate of the performance of each participant on each task. You can then analyze the mean estimates with the familiar linear methods such as ANOVA or Pearson correlation. This is often done in published research, albeit this method discards the information about the precision of the individual performance estimates. A hierarchical approach such as the one used by Vandekerckhove et al. (2011) is a much better idea. See also White et al. (2011) for an application of the drift diffusion model to analysis of flanker task data.

Vandekerckhove, J., Tuerlinckx, F., & Lee, M. D. (2011). Hierarchical diffusion models for two-choice response times. Psychological methods, 16(1), 44.

White, C. N., Ratcliff, R., & Starns, J. J. (2011). Diffusion models of the flanker task: Discrete versus gradual attentional selection. Cognitive psychology, 63(4), 210-238.